# Difference between camel-jbpm and jboss jbpm?

Tags: apache-camel, jbpm

What is the difference between Apache camel-jbpm and jboss jbpm ?
Since Apache camel(2.16.3) is having one component as camel-jbpm.
I am confused which one I should use ? I am integrating with karaf. please suggest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JBoss BPM (business process - a.k.a human workflow) is a project you can find and read more about here:
http://www.jbpm.org/

Apache Camel is an integration library that allows to integrate with a lot of different system. Doing so by using Camel components. One of these components is camel-jbpm that makes it possible/easier to use JBPM from Camel users.

- http://camel.apache.org/jbpm

So if you have an existing BPM system and need to integrate with that from a Camel application or Java application, then using the camel-jpmn can make that (much) easier.

Comment: Thanks Claus. I dont have an existing BPM system. Do I need to integrate jboss jbpm with karaf first then I need to integrate camel with karaf ? I am trying to get the business process in karaf container.

Comment: Here I have demonstrated the usage of component with example projects: http://www.ofbizian.com/2015/10/jboss-fuse-and-jboss-bpm-suite.html

Comment: Getting error like java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jsoup/Jsoup [Message: [Body is null]] Exchange[
 Id ID-55305-1464335463261-3-29
 ExchangePattern     InOnly
  Headers            {CamelJBPMParameters={errorMessage=java.lang.RuntimeException: Something went wrong, contextId=FUSE_BPMS_CONTEXT, exceptionType=class java.lang.RuntimeException, breadcrumbId=ID-55305-1464335463261-3-28, routeId=mainRoute, endpointId=log://com.ofbizian.jbpm.before?multiline=true&showAll=true, firedTime=Fri May 27 14:48:13 IST 2016, exchangeId=ID-55305-1464335463261-3-29}}
 BodyType null
 Body  [Body is null]